# Using a target size that is different to the input size - pytorch autoencoder

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to train an autoencoder using a dataset with 116,247 rows and 51 features. I suspect the issue I am experiencing is due to the format of my training data, but I'm rather new to pytorch, and am finding difficulty researching this problem. Is the issue below resolved by somehow wrapping the dataset in a DataLoader or something similar? Or is the problem something else entirely?

```
class denoising_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder=nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Linear(51,30),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(30,20),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(20,10),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(10,3)
                    )
        
        self.decoder=nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Linear(3,10),
                    nn.ReLU(),            
                    nn.Linear(10,20),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(20,30),
                    nn.ReLU(),
                    nn.Linear(30,51),
                    nn.Tanh()
                    )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        encoded=self.encoder(x)
        decoded=self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded

net = denoising_model()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)

completed_data_copy = completed_data_copy.astype(np.float32)
features = torch.tensor(completed_data_copy.values)
features = features[torch.randperm(features.size()[0])]
print(features.shape)
torch.Size([116247, 51])

for epoch in range(1):

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(features):
        inputs = data

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, features)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 100 == 99:
            print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 100:.10f}')
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')


/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py:530: 
UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([116247, 51])) that is different to 
the input size (torch.Size([51])). This will likely lead to incorrect results 
due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
  return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
```

Comment: How was the input shape defined?

Answer (score 0):

change data to data.view(1, -1) and criterion(outputs, features) to criterion(outputs, inputs):

```
for epoch in range(1):

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(features):
        inputs = data.view(1, -1)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        outputs = net(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, inputs)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 100 == 99:
            print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 100:.10f}')
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Comment: But apart from that, it's not a good idea to feed one data point at a time, instead batachify them.